# Are all maps the same?

Tags: a-dark-room

Is the map randomly generated or is it always the same?  My map currently looks like this:[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are randomly generated, but only once. Your map won't change throughout your entire playthrough. On a new game, however, the map will be different.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the answer is no. The map I had was different.